# JSTL error: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

Here's my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
```

Followed by the html file.  jstl-1.2.jar is located in the WEB-INF folder.  That is the only explanation I've found anywhere else for why this shouldn't work, so I don't understand why I am still having this problem.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  I do not have standard.jar.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the same. The jstl taglibs cannot be found. You need to make sure, that jstl.jar is in your "/WEB-INF/lib" folder, as you can see in Alexei Petrov answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of JSP I was using was not compatible with the version of JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

Tags are correct.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
```

Where in WEB-INF folder it should be under lib.

[image]